Postman - How do I get the id_token out of the "Get New Access Token" response?
I have two collections in Postman. One is for REST calls and the other is for GraphQL. I have the OAuth 2.0 authorization working on the REST collection. To use the token that comes back from that, I have to highlight the token that's returned and copy it to the env variable I use in the GraphQL collection. I can see the request in the console. But I can't seem to find a way to pull that id_token off of the response.
I've tried putting console.log in the Post-reponse of the REST collection, but those are never showing up in the console.
The API collection where the auth occurs. I need it in the GraphQL collection as a variable.
After I click the Get New Access Token button
I would like to be able to automatically set this variable without having to select the full token, right click, and manually set it
Post-response script
Clarifying that the token comes back

ID token not include in OAuth 2.0 spec. , ID token include in OpenID connect spec.. You did not show detail Get Token API but generally get token with scope=openid & profile then get ID token. Also ID token and Access Token are separate part in JWT.

It's not an issue with the token coming back. It's correctly getting it from the API. It's an issue with no clear way, via Postman, to set the token that comes back as a variable.

you can assign variable from tests tab in here

I understand how to do it for a regular request. This is specifically when trying to get and set a variable to the token at the collection level. The post request scripts aren't being fired when getting the auth token.

Your case is redirect URL callback to Postman URL(https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback), const url = new URL(window.location.href); const accessToken = url.searchParams.get("access_token");

I tried setting the callback for auth to that getpostman url. It's still not executing the test scripts.

How to reproduce your callback case?
